# Unable to access Django server running in EC2 instance

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run a Django(or really any server to begin) in an ec2 instance like in this tutorial: https://dev.to/awscommunity-asean/create-and-deploy-python-django-application-in-aws-ec2-instance-4hbm

The issue is that I can't access the server from my browser despite setting my security group in a way that enables traffic from outside.

In the ec2 instance (I am able to ssh in) I have a django server running with `python3 manage.py runserver 0:8000`
I also set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` in `settings.py`

My inbound rules are as follows:
[image]

I try to access the webpage with :8000 with no luck

I would like to know where there are sources for error in this process and if there's anything I can do to test the server. If I missed anything let me know.

Comment: ... none of those rules are for port 8000

Comment: Forgive me I'm new to this. How do I fix this? @BradyDean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your development server is listening on port 8000, create a tcp rule allowing inbound connections on port 8000.